# Develop shiny apps on linux and deploying them as desktop app on a windows machine

Tags: r, shiny, desktop-application

I have developed a shiny app and now wish to share it with some colleagues as a desktop app.
The issue is that I have developed the app on a machine that only has Linux installed on it and my colleagues are using Windows.
I have read several documents on deployment (e.g. [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/) [here](https://oddhypothesis.blogspot.co.il/2016/04/desktop-deployr.html)), but they rely on R-portable which to my understanding is compatible with Windows, not Linux.
I thought about trying to install R-portable via wine, but I wanted to be sure that there isn't a more direct approach to the problem.
Please forgive me if this a dumb question, this is my first attempt at app deployment and I really am about confused, so any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you committed to doing it via desktop? Or could you instead host it on an internal server (say using Shiny Server or rsconnect)?

Comment: I can try Shiny Server (rsconnect requires payment and I don't want to go into expanses over that), but since I don't have any experience in setting up servers I'm afraid it will be time consuming, so I'm keeping this as a last resort at the moment.

Comment: If it is all public info, you could host on shinyapps.io for free!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is not public info.

Comment: Also here's a good guide to setting up shiny server. http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/ Honestly it is likely going to be easier than going through the desktop deployment process. That said, you could also just build it as an R package that people consume and then have them run commands which launch the apps.

Comment: Thanks, will try!